# Azure AppService saving MemoryStream to Blob has a 0 byte file

Tags: c#, azure, asp.net-core

I have the following code to upload `MemoryStreams` to Azure Blob Storage:

```
var pdf = _pdfServices.GeneratePdf(rdPath); // This returns a byte array byte[]

using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream(pdf, false))
{
   // Create a BlobServiceClient object which will be used to create a container client
   BlobServiceClient blobServiceClient =
        new BlobServiceClient(_azureBlob.ConnectionString);

   // Create the container and return a container client object
   BlobContainerClient containerClient = 
        blobServiceClient.GetBlobContainerClient(_azureBlob.ContainerName);

   var blob = containerClient.GetBlobClient(f.Id.ToString());
   
   ms.Position = 0;
   await blob.UploadAsync(ms, true);
}
```

This works from my development machine, and will upload into the Blob container.

However, when I publish the site to an Azure App Service (running Windows or Linux), the resulting file is always 0 bytes.

I'm at a loss as to how to diagnose this, given the local dev and debug all works from Visual Studio.

I'm using the Azure Blob Client v12, hence no `CloudBlockBlob` objects.

Edited with more code, the `ms` is created from a `byte[]` - but it works to  Azure on my local machine and uploads over the internet - just not via an app service. I can try an Azure VM to see if that changes anything?

Comment: Typically this happens when you don't reset the memory stream's position but that's not the case with you as you're doing `ms.Position = 0;`. Can you edit your question and include the complete code?

Comment: @GauravMantri Added some more code as how the process works - the upload is a service layer but the concept is the same.

Comment: Seems `GeneratePdf()` returning an empty `byte[]` is more likely; perhaps add some logging to check whether that's the case.

Comment: @sellotape maybe the case on the app service, but all working locally... How ever a good shout to check!

Comment: @sellotape you were correct, the target was returning no content and hence the byte array was empty. Thanks for the eyes!